# Checking in loop if image exist and actualisation

Tags: javascript, image

I have an array `imglist` which contains images paths.

The below code checks existence of an image and if not found change a style of numB to: display none.

```
var nums = [];
var imgc;
var imgnumb = imglist.length;  
for( var d = 1; d <= imgnumb; d++ ) {  
      imgc = document.createElement('img'); 
      imgc.src = imglist[d];
      imgc.onerror = function() {
      alert(d);
      nums[d] = parseInt(document.getElementById("numB"+d).setAttribute("style", "display:none"));
}}
```

My code is not working and I can't find any problem. Please help me in fixing the error.

Comment: `var imgnumb = img.length;` - the `img` variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes sorry, mistake in copying, corrected.

Comment: You should probably also use [file_exists](http://phpjs.org/functions/file_exists/)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it, but still is there any solution for this code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as `document.getElementById("numB"+d)` does not find the correct element in the DOM and thus failing to set its display value to none.

Make sure to set an ID attribute to your dynamically created elements:

```
imgc = document.createElement('img');
imgc.setAttribute("id", "numB" + d);
```

Comment: I think it is not that, when working in a loop alert(d); is displaying many times for example 97 when imgnumb=96.

Comment: Array indexing starts from 0, thus an array with 10 records will have the indexes for 0 through 9. Change your for loop to: `for( var d = 0; d < imgnumb; d++ )`

Comment: No, an array also is declared from 1.